# SKSpriteNode name to int

Tags: swift, sprite-kit, option-type, skspritenode

I'm trying to convert an `SKSpriteNode` item name to an `Int`...

That's the code:

```
let item = SKSpriteNode(imageNamed: "enemy")
item.name = "1"
```

Then, in `touchesEnded`:

```
guard let touch = touches.first else { return }
let location = touch.location(in: self)
let touchedSKSpriteNode = self.atPoint(location)

processItemTouched(node: touchedSKSpriteNode as! SKSpriteNode)
```

The func `processItemTouched` tries to extract the name of the touched element and converts it to an Int:

```
func processItemTouched(node: SKSpriteNode) {
    let num: Int =  Int(node.name)  // Error
}
```

But there is an error: "Value of optional type 'Int?' not unwrapped; did you mean to use '!' or '?'?"

After clicking on **Fix-it**, it becomes:

```
let num: Int =  Int(node.name)!   // Error, again
```

But another error appears: "Value of optional type 'String?' not unwrapped; did you mean to use '!' or '?'?"

Finally, it's working, after fixing:

```
let num: Int =  Int(node.name!)!
```

It works but there's a problem: if I try to verify if `num != nil`, Xcode says that "Comparing non-optional value of type 'Int' to nil always returns true".

Is there a way to avoid this alert?

Comment: Can you please elaborate why you need to name sprite nodes with an Int? It sounds like there should be a more elegant/typesafe/standard way of achieving this goal.

Comment: What node name would give a value of 'nil' for your int?

Comment: I'm trying to develop a Memory Card game for learning purpose and assign a progressive number as a name to any card looked to be a good time saving idea...

A nil value could comes up touching the background image, I think... I can assign a name to every SKNode in the scene... Could it be a solution?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are using `Int` type construtor `Int?(String)` which means it needs a `String` and returns an optional `Int` (`Int?`).

`node.name` is an optional property of `SKNode`, because nodes can have no name. So you have been suggested to force dereferencing (but this is very dangerous). You can provide a default value as `node.name ?? <default>` or use the if-let:

```
if let name = node.name {
   // do something with name in the case it exists!
}
```

Then you tried to store the `Int?` produced in a variable of type `Int`, and the IDE suggested you to force dereferencing it (again a bad thing). Again you can provide a default value `let i : Int = Int(node.name ?? "0") ?? 0` or use the if-let pattern:

```
if let name = node.name, let i = Int(name) {
   // do want you want with i and name...
} else {
   // something bad happened
}
```

Answer (score 1):

This is a tricky situation, since both the name of the node and the result of the conversation can be nil.

I'd suggest providing a default value for the name using `??`, forcefully unwrapping the optional with `!` is very inelegant and dangerous (if a node does not have a name and you try to use this function with it, your app will crash).

You should either:

- declare `num` as an **optional** (either explicitly or by leaving out the type altogether):

  ```
  let num = Int(node.name ?? "") //Int?
  ```
- provide a **default value** for `num`:

  ```
  let num = Int(node.name ?? "") ?? 0 //Int
  ```

[Learn more about optionals here.](https://developer.apple.com/library/content/documentation/Swift/Conceptual/Swift_Programming_Language/TheBasics.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40014097-CH5-ID330)

Comment: Unfortunately the two suggestions can't avoid the "Comparing non-optional value of type 'Int' to nil always returns true" alert...

Comment: @Alchemy for the 2nd example, you shouldn't get that problem because num isn't an optional - if the node has no name or a name that can't be converted to an Int, then `num` is set to 0.